# Closing cursor in onPostExecute renders nothing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using AsyncTask to load data from a SQLite Database and then providing data to a Recycler View using a StaggeredLayoutManager and CustomListAdapter.

If I don't close the cursor of doInBackground method in the onPostExecuteMethod, the transition from the previous activity is laggy, and android logcat says "Skipped 52 frames".

If I do close the cursor, at the end of the Post Execute method, the lag doesn't occur, but nothing is rendered inside the Activity. (Recycler View renders nothing.)

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Void) {             
        c.close();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
          new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new MyTask().execute();
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.swipeRefreshColors));

    }
```

### doInBackground method

```
       try {           
                myDb = new SavedData(getApplicationContext());
                writeableDatabase = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
                final String[] projection = {SavedData.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID,
                        SavedData.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE,
                        SavedData.COLUMN_NAME_SHIPPING,
                        SavedData.COLUMN_NAME_WEIGHT,
                        SavedData.COLUMN_NAME_PRODUCT};
                sortOrder = BookSave.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " DESC";
                c = writeableDatabase.query(
                        SavedData.TABLE_NAME,  
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null,
                        sortOrder
                );
                m = new MyListCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), c);
                gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(NUM, 1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }
```

### The BaseAdapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private Context mContext;

    private Cursor mCursor;

    private boolean mDataValid;

    private int mRowIdColumn;

    private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;

    public CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
        mDataValid = cursor != null;
        mRowIdColumn = mDataValid ? mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id") : -1;
        mDataSetObserver = new NotifyingDataSetObserver();
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIdColumn);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, mCursor);
    }

    /**
     * Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If there is an existing cursor it will be
     * closed.
     */
    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
        if (old != null) {
            old.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor.  Unlike
     * {@link #changeCursor(Cursor)}, the returned old Cursor is <em>not</em>
     * closed.
     */
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (newCursor == mCursor) {
            return null;
        }
        final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if (oldCursor != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
            oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mCursor = newCursor;
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
                mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
            mRowIdColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mRowIdColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }

    private class NotifyingDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
    }
}
```

### The extended Adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyListCursorAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<MyListCursorAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "MyListCursorAdapter";

    public MyListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.productList, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final Cursor cursor) {
        Book myListItem = Book.fromCursor(cursor);
        viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(myListItem.getTitle());
        viewHolder.shippingTextView.setText(myListItem.getAShipping());
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+viewHolder.isRecyclable());
    }



    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView shippingTextView;
        public TextView titleTextView;
        public LinearLayout insideCard;
        public Button payButton;
        public View seperator;
        public CardView cv;
        public View view;

        public ViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            DisplayMetrics DM = new DisplayMetrics();
            display.getMetrics(DM);
            payButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.readButton);
            seperator = view.findViewById(R.id.separator);
            titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            insideCard = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.insideCard);
            insideCard.getLayoutParams().width = (DM.widthPixels / 2) - 24;
            shippingTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shippingTextView);


//typeface
            Typeface light = Typeface.createFromAsset(titleTextView.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
            titleTextView.setTypeface(light);
            Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(authorTextView.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/thinItalic.ttf");
            shippingTextView.setTypeface(regular);

            payButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent goToCheckout = new Intent(view.getContext(), ShowReader.class);
                    goToCheckout.putExtra("PRODUCT_NAME", titleTextView.getText());
                    view.getContext().startActivity(goToCheckout);
                }
            });


            setWidth((DM.widthPixels / 2) - 24);
        }

        public void setWidth(int a) {
            a = a - 8 * 4;
            payButton.getLayoutParams().width = a;
            seperator.getLayoutParams().width = a;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Move **c.close();**  in _doInBackground()_ method.

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Show your code for database.

Comment: How does that matter?

Comment: can you add the doInBackground() code?

Comment: @Droidekas added the required code.

Comment: I think your problem is not related to your cursor, your adapter probably is doing heavy things on the main thread.

Comment: How do I approach it and what can be done to rectify the issue?

Comment: @Abhi post your adapter

Comment: try closing after 
 m = new MyListCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), c); this line
c.close();

Comment: What happens if you put `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` inside `onRefresh()` method. and what is `MyTask`? is it the same class which contains these all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
//typeface
            Typeface light = Typeface.createFromAsset(titleTextView.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
            titleTextView.setTypeface(light);
            Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(authorTextView.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/thinItalic.ttf");
            shippingTextView.setTypeface(regular);
```

every time you are going to create new `ViewHolder` you are going to read from file. That is heavy operation when you do it multiple times. So one solution is reading just once and caching the fonts. So let's see some code:

```
public class MyFontProvider {

    private static final String TAG = MyFontProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    private Map<String, Typeface> mCache;

    private static volatile MyFontProvider sInstance;

    public static MyFontProvider getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (MyFontProvider.class) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = new MyFontProvider();
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private MyFontProvider() {
        mCache = new Hashtable<>();
    }

    public synchronized Typeface getFont(String assetPath, Context context) {
        if (!mCache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
            try {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), assetPath);
                mCache.put(assetPath, t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting typeface (" + assetPath + " ) " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
        return mCache.get(assetPath);
    }
}
```

Now you can change

```
//typeface
            Typeface light = Typeface.createFromAsset(titleTextView.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
            titleTextView.setTypeface(light);
            Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(authorTextView.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/thinItalic.ttf");
            shippingTextView.setTypeface(regular);
```

to

```
//typeface
            titleTextView.setTypeface(MyFontProvider.getInstance().getFont("fonts/light.ttf",this));
            shippingTextView.setTypeface(MyFontProvider.getInstance().getFont("fonts/thinItalic.ttf",this));
```

And also it is a good idea to store a font path as a `public final static String` so you can change it in one place and do not have to modify multiple files.

Comment: Awesome. Solves the problem. I guess, the file system has its cost.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't close the cursor until you are completely done with it.  You've lost your source of data once you've done that, so that's why you're not seeing anything after closing it.

Have you analyzed your adapter yet?  Given that you have lag when you don't close the cursor, but none with you do, there is always the possibility that you're not being efficient in creating your views

Comment: How can I efficiently create the views?

Comment: can you post more of the code? it's hard to guess what's going on with just snippets